How to set download path in Selenium + geckodriver + Firefox
I want to setup specific downloads path using selenium, but files still downloading in /root/Downloads/
What I can change to set a specific path?
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

download_dir = "specific_path" 

firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
firefox_options.add_argument("--browser.download.folderList=2")  # 0 - Default, 1 - Desktop, 2 - Specified location
firefox_options.add_argument("--browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting=False")
firefox_options.add_argument(f"--browser.download.dir={download_dir}")
firefox_options.add_argument("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=application/pdf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")

# Настройка веб-драйвера
service = FirefoxService("/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=firefox_options)

